# Why does a static hide an overridden method at compile time?

Tags: c#

Given:

```
class BaseClass
{
    public virtual void M(int x) 
    { 

    }
}

class Derived : BaseClass
{
    public override void M(int x)
    {
        base.M(x);
    }

    static void M(object x)
    {

    }

    static void Main()
    {
        var d = new Derived();
        d.M(0);
    }
}
```

Error:

> Member 'Derived.M(object)' cannot be accessed with an instance
>   reference; qualify it with a type name instead

Looking at the C# 4.0 spec section 7.4 (Member Lookup) the first bullet point reads:

> A member lookup of a name N with K type parameters in a type T is
>   processed as follows:
>
> [...] Members that include an override modifier are excluded from the
>   set [of accessible members named N]

From this I conclude that the override `Derived.M` is no longer accessible.  Instead, the compiler must refer to `BaseClass.M`.

However, this does not explain why adding a static `Derived.M` suddenly causes a compilation error.  The compiler can now only see the static member  `Derived.M` and concludes that this member is an invalid call.  If I remove the static `Derived.M` then compilation succeeds.

Why does this happen?

Comment: http://www.akadia.com/services/dotnet_polymorphism.html

Comment: It appears to be a problem with object as the parameter of the static method.  If I change that parameter to a string, it works fine.

Comment: As interesting as these questions can be for someone like Eric Lippert who's forced (or gets to, really) to try to write compilers who can solve problems like this, the real lesson here is to just not create tough problems for the compiler in the first place and avoid giving lots of identifiers the same name when distinct names are equally effective.

Comment: @Servy - Well sure, but on large projects with many developers I have to be able to manage code written by devs with many different skill levels.  Not to mention, dealing with 3rd party vendors/libraries.  I can't always control the design, sometimes I just have to deal with it.

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey If a 3rd party created both of these classes then you'd think they realize that almost any use of the derived class involves this error, and they'd catch it pretty quick.  If only the base class is theirs, then I'd ask why the derived class needs a static method named `M`.

Comment: @Servy - I find it difficult to accept best practices at face value.  If I can go through these types of problems and understand what makes them difficult...then I can appreciate the best practice and better remember to follow it. Otherwise, I often feel like I'm parroting.  I dunno how many devs think like that and I apologize if it offends anyone.

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey Practices that make it hard for the compiler to figure out what should be done also have a tendency to make it hard for a *person* to figure out what should be done (in this case, what method should be called).  By being overly ambiguous you force developers to think about which method is being called.  Don't make me think!  That it is also hard for the compiler isn't the root problem, it's just an indication of the *real* problem, which is code that isn't as readable as it could be.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following steps seem to happen and are together the reason for your compiler error:

- Step 1: Because of the part from 7.4. you quoted, the instance version of `M` is removed, leaving the compiler only with the static one. The parameter type of the static one is `object`, which is compatible to `int`. The method name matches, too.
- Step 2: Member lookup finished, because a matching method has been found (correct name, compatible parameters), no need to go up the inheritance chain.
- Step 3: Only now is checked if the method is an instance method or a static one.

I can't really quote a single sentence of the spec proving this, but neither §7.4 (Member lookup) nor §3.5 (Accessability) talk about `static` vs. instance, so I assume this fact is simply not taken into account *at all* when doing a member lookup.

Relevant parts from §7.4 seem to be:

> A member lookup of a name N with K type parameters in a type T is processed as follows:
>
> - First, a set of accessible members named N is determined:
>   [...]
>   The set consists of all accessible (§3.5) members named N in T, including inherited members and the accessible members named N in object. If T is a constructed type, the set of members is obtained by substituting type arguments as described in §10.3.2. Members that include an override modifier are excluded from the set.

The way I understand this part it is like explained above: It would return both the instance method and the static one and will then remove the instance one, because it has the `override` modifier.
Only the static method is left at this point.

It closes with this:

> Finally, [...], the result of the lookup is determined:
> if the set contains only methods, then this group of methods is the result of the lookup.

So, the result is the static method.

Obviously, this problem only happens in circumstances where you have a class hierarchy and one of the derived classes declares a static method with the same name and compatible parameters.

Adding such a static method to an existing class is a case where simply adding something to a class is still a *breaking change*.

Although I am pretty sure you know how to solve the compiler error, I will still state it, to have a complete answer:
Use any of the base classes as the compile time type of your variable. The runtime type still can be the derived type, that's not the problem:

```cs
BaseClass d          = new Derived();
// ^                         ^
// compile time type        runtime type
```

Comment: "The parameter type of the static one is object, which is compatible to int.".  This.  If I change the parameter to something that is not compatible with int, I don't get an error.  I tried this with various compatible and non-compatible data types and all behaved as expected.

Comment: Finally found it.  The core of the problem is defined in 7.6.5.1 - "The set of candidate methods is reduced to contain only methods from the most derived types".  Because `Derived.M` is more derived than `BaseClass.M`, base class is removed as an option.  Thus..the error.

Answer (score 4):

Daniel's answer is correct; a brief summary of the relevant rules is:

- methods in a more derived class are always considered better than methods in a less-derived class
- overriding methods are considered to be methods in the class which first declares them, not the class which overrides them
- resolving which method, if any, is "best" happens *before* the check to see if the receiver is an instance and the method is static. (And also before generic type parameter constraints are checked.)

This last rule is a bit odd, but it does make some sense. See my comments and nikov's comments on pages 290 and 291 of the hardbound annotated C# 4 specification for an extended discussion of this specific rule.

Also, for an analysis of an interesting corner case where this rule intersects the `Color Color` rule, see

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/07/06/color-color.aspx

Comment: Where would we find this discussion?  I don't see a version of the spec on MSDN that allows comments.

Comment: @EdT: Go to ericlippert.com. Click on the link on the right hand sidebar that says "The C# Programming Language". Purchase the book; the annotations are worth the price. Wait until it arrives. Turn to page 290.

Comment: The C# Programming Language is pretty intense and very much awesome.  Not for beginners, but this book and Jon Skeet's book are worth every dime:  http://www.manning.com/skeet3/

Comment: @EricLippert: No fair being snarky after the edit! :P  Thanks though, I'll pick it up.